# How to avoid eslint rule no-unneeded-ternary violation: 'Unnecessary use of conditional expression for default assignment'

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

This is my code

```
class Message extends Component {

  render() {
    const { message, timeToRedirect } = this.props;
    const time = timeToRedirect ? timeToRedirect : TIME_TO_REDIRECT  // eslint flags this line
```

The idea is that if the parameter `timeToRedirect` is zero or undefined, I will assign a constant `TIME_TO_REDIRECT` to variable `time`

However eslint flags this as a violation of the rule `no-unneeded-ternary`: 'Unnecessary use of conditional expression for default assignment'.

I can certainly rewrite it to

```
let time = timeToRedirect;
if (!timeToRedirect) {
   time = TIME_TO_REDIRECT;
 }
```

but it is less elegant in my opinion.

Is there a better way to rewrite the ternary expression?

I am currently using these npm packages

```
"babel-eslint": "7.1.0",
"eslint": "3.9.1",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "12.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "1.16.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.2.3",
"eslint-plugin-react": "6.5.0",
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[They want you](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unneeded-ternary) to use the [OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()):

```
const time = timeToRedirect || TIME_TO_REDIRECT;
```

Notice that to catch `undefined` values you could also just use a default intialiser in the destructuring:

```
render() {
    const { message, timeToRedirect: time = TIME_TO_REDIRECT } = this.props;
    …
```

Comment: Thx for the great answer. Where can I read more about this  syntax `timeToRedirect: time = TIME_TO_REDIRECT` ? It is new to me

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment